# Proof of norm of a solution of a differential equation is less than the norm of equation itself.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces, finite-element-method

Consider the problem
$$-eu''+xu'+u=f$$
$x$ is defined on the interval $I=[0,L]$. $u(0)=u'(L)=0$
where $e > 0$ is a constant. Prove that the solution satisfies
$||eu''||≤ ||f||$ where norm is the $L_2$-norm on $I$.

Hi everyone, I'm new to study of pure mathematics hence very inexperienced in proofs. I tried to use triangle inequality or Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in many ways, I tried to write the integrals explicitly but nothing has helped. How should we proceed? What is the strategy at least? Thanks.

This question is the exercise 2.9 of "M. G. Larson, F. Bengzon, The Finite Element Method: Theory, Implementation, and Applications, Springer, 2014 "

Comment: Check out section 2.6 of Brenner-Scott. Unfortunately I cannot give a direct answer with formulae. The general idea is energy method estimates as it is usually done for proving coercitivity of the bilinear form in the weak formulation. The non-symmetric term should be estimated through the sum of the squares with suitable coefficients. Though I'd expect that there will be a condition on $e$ and $L$ in your case because of that.